# Google Chart Timeline Years 0-99

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm working on a project that will utilize a Google Chart [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) to display events in a fictional universe. As such, I need the timeline to start at year 0.

I've done some research and found mixed messaging on why a  new Date() entry of '99' for example defaults to '1999'

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnytx2z7/) for the timeline I am working on.

Sample:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Term' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Films', 'Epsiode I: The Phantom Menace', new Date(0000, 0, 1), new Date(0001, 0, 1) ],
      [ 'Films', 'Episode II: Attack Of The Clones',            new Date(0010, 0, 1), new Date(0011, 0, 1) ],
      [ 'Films', 'Episode III: Revenge Of The Sith',            new Date(0013, 0, 1), new Date(0014, 0, 1) ],
      [ 'Books', 'Dark Disciple',        new Date(0012, 0, 1),  new Date(0013, 0, 1) ],
      [ 'Books', 'Ahsoka',          new Date(0014, 0, 1), new Date(0014, 0, 1) ],
      [ 'TV', 'The Clone Wars',         new Date(0010, 0, 1),  new Date(0012, 0, 1) ]]);

    var options = {
      timeline: { showRowLabels: true, colorByRowLabel: true  }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

What I need is the ability to create entries from years 0 through 99AD without defaulting to 1900+. How can this be accomplished? I appreciate any assistance.